VoIP Phone isn't getting DHCP after disconnecting the SD-WAN
My network was as follow :
MPLS --> VeloCloud(SD-WAN) --> Meraki MX100 --> Cisco SF350
I removed the VeloCloud and MPLS and got a Modem from ATT and now my network look like this:
ATT Modem --> Meraki MX100 --> Cisco SF350
Everything works fine except the VoIP Phones. Of course, the phone were connected to the Cisco SF350, and they're not getting an IP, but can give out an IP to laptop/PC through ethernet. When I look at their status I see the IPv4 on the phone 10.126.79.60, this looks like the ATT IP's which I whitelisted in the Meraki.
When I connect the phone to the Modem directly it lights up and get an IPv4 192.168.x.x as expected and make/receive phone calls.
I have thoroughly looked at the DHCP on both Meraki and Cisco and then VLANS and they seems correct(Not an expert on the topic)
Here is how my configurations look like in the Meraki and SF350.
MERAKI MX100:



Here is My Cisco SF350:







What am I missing out here ?

Duh, I wiresharked through my laptop that was connected to the phone, and was able to identify the ip that it was arp requesting too.
